# Asp.net core - What's the purpose of using Anonymous types in RedirectToPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have seen people use anonymous types as parameters in RedirectToPage. For example,

```
return RedirectToPage("/BlogPosts/Edit", new { id = blogId });
```

I found the result would be the same if I use

```
return RedirectToPage("/BlogPosts/Edit", blogId);
```

Almost all the codes I saw use anonymous types as parameters, so I'm curious about the reasons behind this.
Thank you.

Comment: On your 2nd example, how would you pass 2 parameters?  Either method is acceptable if there is only 1 parameter, but for consistency, the first one is a 'better' repeatable pattern.

Comment: You may use f12 to check is there any differences between the rendered url.